# No error, but code won't run, Exception in Application start method JavaFX

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, exception, javafx, javafx-8

I made a simple UI using Eclipse, there is no sign of error like usual, and I follow the code as close as I can from a tutorial. While it doesn't show any error, it still won't run, and automatically open a debugging panel, and says that, "Exception in Application start method."

Below is my code :

```
package groupProject;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Try extends Application
{
    Stage window;
    Scene newUserScene;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception 
{
    window = primaryStage;
    window.setTitle("Automated Teller Machine");

    GridPane nUserGrid = new GridPane();
    nUserGrid.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    nUserGrid.setVgap(8);
    nUserGrid.setHgap(10);

    //New matric card - Label 1
    Label newMatricLabel = new Label("Matric Number: ");
    GridPane.setConstraints(newMatricLabel,0,0);//Set Position
    TextField newMatricInput = new TextField();     
    GridPane.setConstraints(newMatricInput,1,0);//Set position

    //New user name - Label 2
    Label newUsername = new Label("Your name: ");
    GridPane.setConstraints(newUsername,0,1);//Set position
    TextField newUsernameInput = new TextField();
    GridPane.setConstraints(newUsernameInput,1,1);//Set Position

    //Pin number -  Label 3
    Label newPin = new Label("Your pin: ");
    GridPane.setConstraints(newPin,0,2);//Set position
    TextField newPinInput = new TextField();
    GridPane.setConstraints(newPinInput,1,2);//Set position

    //Deposit - Label 4
    Label newDepositValue = new Label("Deposit: ");
    GridPane.setConstraints(newDepositValue,0,3);//Set position
    TextField newDepositInput = new TextField();
    GridPane.setConstraints(newDepositInput,1,1);//Set position


    //Create submit button---//
    Button submitEntree = new Button("Submit");
    GridPane.setConstraints(submitEntree,1,4);//Set Position
    nUserGrid.getChildren().addAll(newMatricLabel,newMatricInput,newMatricInput,newUsername,newUsernameInput,newPin,newPinInput,newDepositValue,newDepositInput,submitEntree);//add all to GridPane

     newUserScene = new Scene(nUserGrid,500,500);

        window.setScene(newUserScene);
        window.show();      
    }
}
```

The full message that appears on the debugging perspective are :

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Grid hgap=10.0, vgap=8.0, alignment=TOP_LEFT
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:454)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:103)
    at groupProject.Try.start(Try.java:61)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application groupProject.Try
```

The button and the user input doesn't have any action-related to it yet at this moment but will do in the future.

What is the cause of the error and how do I fix this kind of error so that it can run and show the user interface  that I made? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `duplicate children added: parent = Grid hgap=10.0, vgap=8.0, alignment=TOP_LEFT`

Comment: You have added `newMatricInput` twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```
nUserGrid.getChildren().addAll(newMatricLabel,newMatricInput,newMatricInput,newUsername,newUsernameInput,newPin,newPinInput,newDepositValue,newDepositInput,submitEntree);//add all to GridPane
```

You add `newMatricInput` twice. Remove one.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks. It works. I never thought and never knew that a duplicate element will cause an error. Guess I learn something new again today. Thanks!

Comment: The [Node documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) states: "If a program adds a child node to a Parent (including Group, Region, etc) and that node is already a child of a different Parent or the root of a Scene, the node is automatically (and silently) removed from its former parent".  I guess trying to add the same node twice to the same parent, like this case, just generates an error.

Comment: Indeed, the documentation continues: "If a program attempts to modify the scene graph in any other way that violates the above rules, an exception is thrown, the modification attempt is ignored and the scene graph is restored to its previous state." The "above rules" include that a node may occur once in the scene graph, so this would violate those rules, and accordingly throws an exception.